Create a token extension which taxes on buying and selling but not on transferring
How do we create a token extension that taxes on buying and selling but not on transferring tokens?
I am looking to build a token which

has taxes for buying and selling, not on transferring
has an exempt function which exempts particular addresses to not pay taxes


"buying and selling" is just a token transfer, you may need a custom transfer hook program to implement the custom feature you're looking for
